# Understanding implicit <:< parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I wrote this example

```
class TestMatch[T](private val t: T){
    def test()(implicit ev: T <:< Option[Int]) = println(ev(t).get)
}
```

and a test for it

```
val tm = TestMatch(Some(10))
tm.test() //fine

val tm2 = TestMatch(10)
tm2.test() //compilation error
```

The question is who creates the `implicit ev: T <:< Option[Int]` when I invoke `test` method? I know I didn't. Maybe the compiler is aware of `implicit <:<` and know what to do with it.

Documenation of `<:<`was not quite clear

> To constrain any abstract type T that's in scope in a method's
>   argument list (not just the method's own type parameters) **simply add**
>   **an implicit argument of type** `T <:< U`, where `U` is the required
>   upper bound; or for lower-bounds, use: `L <:< T`, where `L` is the
>   required lower bound.

Does it mean that the compiler will take the rest on itself? I just add the `implicit ev: T1 <:< T2`?

Comment: Based on the recent questions you have posted you seem to have some glaring gaps in your knowledge of Scala. I would advise that you read a good book on the Scala language and Scala programming.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet compiles because of `Predef.identity`, which means you can always implicitly convert type `T` to type `T` (in this case `Option[Int]`). Otherwise, you would need to bring an implicit into scopre by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that the compiler will take the rest on itself?

The compiler will search for an implicit in scope. If it finds a match, it will provide it, if it can't, you'll get a compilation error. With your example, the compiler finds that `Some[Int]` adheres to the implicit requirement of `Some[Int] <:< Option[Int]` as it is a direct subtype of `Option[Int]`.

You can see this when compiling the code with `scalac`:

```
val tm: TestMatch[Some[Int]] = new TestMatch[Some[Int]](scala.Some.apply[Int](10));
tm.test()(scala.this.Predef.$conforms[Some[Int]]);
```

Where's for `Int` (your second example), there is no implicit in scope matching the requirement, and `Int` is not a subtype of `Option[Int]`.

Comment: Any idea why adding this kind of things does not work ? `implicit def nonZeroInt(i: Int): Option[Int] = if (i == 0) None else Some(i)` (I added at the same level as the call to `test`)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will try to look for implicit parameters in various predefined places. If it cant find them it will throw an error. This link might help: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much a link-only answer

Comment: Ok, I could delete it if you want. I thought it will be easier to see all the places the compiler looks for implicit through this image, instead of having to type them.

Comment: I think the link is useful, but you should try to add some value to it. Don't delete your answer just for me :p